# Why does AdBlock block my Header in symfony?

Tags: html, adblock

I don't understand why **AdBlock** is blocking my header 
This my header

*show.html.twig*

```
{% block body %}
<div class="ad-title" style="background-image: url({{ ad.coverImage }})">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ad.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{ad.introduction}}</p>
        <p class="h2">
            <strong>{{ad.rooms}} chambres</strong> pour <strong>{{ad.price}}&euro;</strong> par nuit
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Réserver !</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have class `ad-title`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cause your div is count as an ad with your class name "ad-title", edit it and it will work

Answer (score 2):

Adblock does some very simple generic filtering based on element id.

If you have the word "ad", "banner", "affiliate" or other common advertising terms as part of your id, your page element may be blocked by adblockers.

Comment: Thank you, I ll change all my ids